# $\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{a^x\sin(bx)-b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx)-\tan(ax)}$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

Determine
$$\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{a^x\sin(bx)-b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx)-\tan(ax)}.$$
Considering $a$ not equal to $b$, I tried to do this by dividing $\tan(bx)$ and $\tan(ax)$ by $bx$ and $ax$ respectively but I think its not right. Am I allowed to this as this was on further simplifying (doing the same with sine in numerator) giving the correct answer which was $1$.

Comment: Use mathjax tools and show us your attempt.

Comment: I am new to this so I don't know what mathjax is

Comment: Have a look at this https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I tried Desmos doesn't it give fluctuating answers?

Comment: umm its actually x tends to 0 not infinity

Comment: @arc why not try L'Hospital's rule??

Comment: @RAHUL I guess that my answer works

Comment: I guess L'Hopital is the only way

Comment: @RAHUL I have corrected it.. I guess it's okay now

Comment: @arc I have edited my answer

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved by comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{a^x\sin(bx)-b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx)-\tan(ax)}$$
$$\lim_ {x\to 0} \frac{a^x\frac{\sin(bx)}{x}-b^x\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}}{\frac{\tan(bx)}{x}-\frac{\tan(ax)}{x}}$$

- $$\color{blue}{\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(kx)}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\tan(kx)}{x}=k}$$
- $$\implies \frac{a^0b-b^0a}{b-a}=1$$
- You can divide with $x$ as $x\to 0 \neq0$

Comment: This cleared my doubt thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^{x}sin(bx)-b^{x}sin(ax)}{tan(bx)-tan(ax)}$$
Since it's of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ in the direct substitution. L'hopital rule can be used.
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{a^{x}bcos(bx)-b^{x}acos(ax)+a^{x}\ln(a)sin(bx)-b^{x}\ln(b)sin(ax)}{bsec^{2}(bx)-asec^{2}(ax)}$$
Now directly put $x=0$ which gives us
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{b-a}{b-a}$$ which is $1$

Answer (score 1):

Use L'Hospital's rule to say
\begin{align*}
L &= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x\sin(bx) - b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx) - \tan(ax)}\\
&= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(a^x\sin(bx) - b^x\sin(ax))}{\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(bx) - \tan(ax))}\\
&= \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x\ln(a)\sin(bx) + ba^x\cos{bx} - b^x\ln(b)\sin(ax) - ab^x\cos(ax)}{b\sec^2(bx) -a\sec^2(ax)}\\
&= \frac{1\times\ln(a)\times 0+b\times 1\times 1-1\times\ln(b)\times 0-a\times 1\times 1}{b-a}\\
&=1
\end{align*}
hence completing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The given limit to be evaluated is $L = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x\sin(bx) - b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx) - \tan(ax)}$, which becomes $\frac{0}0$ on direct substitution.

Therefore, by L'Hospital's rule (not sure of the spelling) :
$$L = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x\sin(bx) - b^x\sin(ax)}{\tan(bx) - \tan(ax)} = \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(a^x\sin(bx) - b^x\sin(ax))}{\frac{d}{dx}(\tan(bx) - \tan(ax))} =  \lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{a^x\ln(a)\sin(bx) + ba^x\cos{bx} - b^x\ln(b)\sin(ax) - ab^x\cos(ax)}{b\sec^2(bx) -a\sec^2(ax)}$$

Now on substituting $x = 0$, $$L = \frac{0 +b\times 1 \times \cos(0) - 0 - a \times 1 \times \cos(0)}{b - a} = 1$$

**NB:** the end result is a definite value if $a \neq b$

Comment: There is a mistake. Derivative of $a^{x}$ wrt $x$ is $a^{x}\ln(a)$

Comment: @RAHUL Oh thanks... I shall delete my nonsense now :D

Comment: @RAHUL I chose to edit it.. my steps were partially correct except for my oblivion when it came to the derivative.. what my teacher once said was true.. thanks again

Comment: Well it looks fine now. By the way, I was just being curious what did your teacher advice

Comment: @RAHUL he had advised all of us students that one is very likely to mistake the derivative as well as the evaluation of limits of the expression $a^x$ for $x^a$ form and lose marks... so yeah, he turned out to be true when it came to that :D